# How to delete all directories except directories pointed by symlink

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I have below directory structure.

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 22 07:03 TEEST  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 24 05:33 BEE-TES  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 24 10:53 ONE  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 25 09:50 TWO  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   28 May 25 09:50 previous -> TWO  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jun  1 11:00 TEMP  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   28 Jun  1 11:00 current -> TEMP
```

How to remove all the directories, except those pointed by symlinks ?

Answer (score 5):

```
{ find . -type l -exec readlink {} \; ; find . -type d -exec basename {} \; ; } | sort | uniq -u | tail -n +2 | xargs rmdir
```

In slow-mo:

- `find . -type l -exec readlink {} \;` finds the links and lists the corresponding directories
- `find . -type d -exec basename {} \;` finds and lists the directories
- the output of the commands in braces lists all directories once, except those that are the target of links that appear twice
- `sort | uniq -u | tail -n +2` keeps only the unique names (so, those directories that are not linked to) and removes `.`
- `xargs rmdir` drops the directories. Replace with `rm -r` to remove their contents.

Comment: Warning: this may work for the OP's directory structure but *in general* these issues may appear: (1) What if there's a symlink linking to `./TWO` or `TWO/`? (2) What if there's a symlink linking to a non-directory? (3) What if there's a symlink linking to some directory elsewhere (i.e. not in the current working directory)? // Therefore be careful with `rmdir` or (especially) `rm -r`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ find /some/symlinks/* -type l -exec sh -c "readlink {} | xargs basename" \; ; find /some/folders/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -prune -exec basename {} \;  ; } | sort | uniq -u | awk '{print "/some/folders/"$0}' | xargs rm -r
```

This can handle multiple types of symlinks in different directories.

```
find /some/symlinks/* -type l -exec sh -c "readlink {} | xargs basename" \;
```

Find symlinks and acquire the basename of directory.

```
find //some/folders/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -prune -exec basename {} \;
```

Find all basenames from where the file link.  Don't go subdirectory and prune so you only get folder names

```
sort | uniq -u
```

Sort and find the ones the are no linked.

```
awk '{print "/some/folders/"$0}'
```

Put the directory back.

```
xargs rm -r
```

Delete the folder.