# How to delete all directories except last 2 directories and the symlink pointed to those directories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script, ruby

I have below directory structure.

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 22 07:03 TEEST  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 24 05:33 BEE-TES  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 24 10:53 ONE  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 25 09:50 TWO  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   28 May 25 09:50 previous -> TWO  
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jun  1 11:00 TEMP  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   28 Jun  1 11:00 Current -> TEMP
```

How to keep or preserve only the last two directories which are modified recently including the symlinks and their respective directories pointed to them?

I have tired the solution in this post
[How to delete all directories except directories pointed by symlink](https://superuser.com/questions/1215370/how-to-delete-all-directories-except-directories-pointed-by-symlink)

but that one is even deleting the directories pointing to symlink only keeping the broken symlink.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad form to parse the output of `ls`, but if you use normal filenames, you could try it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
qty_keep=2

count=0

ls -t | while read name ; do
if [ $count -lt $qty_keep ] ; then
    if [ -d "$name" ] ; then
        count=$((count+1))
        echo "Keeping dir nr $count: $name"
    else
        echo "$name is not a dir; skipping"
    fi
else
    if [ -d "$name" ] ; then
        count=$((count+1))
        echo "Removing dir nr $count: $name"
        # rm -rf "$name"
    else
        echo "$name is not a dir; skipping"
    fi
fi
```

As you may have guessed, this will do nothing until you un-comment the `rm` line, but you should try it as a first dry-run with the comment to see that it does what you want.